# CEWP on homepage to hide quick launch working with site collection admin only

Tags: web-part, permissions

I have a homepage where I have created a Conent Editor WebPart and inside the html I've placed the css code to hide the quick launch. After that I've created a subsite in which I wanted to show the quick launch.

Being a site collection administrator when i browser the site it works perfectly like when I click on homepage it turns off the quick launch and when I visit subsite it turns on the way I want. But when I sign in with other normal visitor (different user) and click on homepage it still shows the quick launch. Whats is causing the problem? Permission issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, does the cewp link to a file stored elsewhere? If so make sure that file is checked in and approved and that all users have read access to it.

Also ensure the page the cewp resides on is checked in and approved.

Comment: Pirate i didnt put the CSS in any file and link it...i just used the content editor webpart..went into html editor and copied the code..like the old days where we had source editor..do u think i should put the css in a txt file and instead of copy the code directly set a link to a file?

Comment: When you put the css in a file and store the file in a document library maintenance will be easier, but it isn't necessary. Are you sure you the page is checked in and published?

Comment: well yes off course but will definitely recheck tomorrow as i am out somewhere...revert back soon.

Comment: Also ensure the page the cewp is on is checked in and approved.

Comment: Guys thank you so much. Yeah I forgot to CHECKED IN the Home.aspx :) ..silly mistake but learned my lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Page -'View Source' and check what's happening behind the scene for the page when logged in as admin and as a normal user. May be the css style works for admin users and the same div tags are hidden for normal users. In that case try hiding it with div tags that appear for the normal user.